# Count the checked checkboxes in gridview

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I need to count the checked checkboxes in my gridview, but I don't know how to do it. Maybe I could use JavaScript and save the count in a textbox with style display none. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you need to do this on the server or on the client?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote both client and server side ways of doing this, have a look at them and choose the one which suits you best!

Please note I've used [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for the client side logic as it's the more modern way of manipulating the DOM on the client

**Source:**

%>

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetMarriedEmployees() {
        var counter = 0;
        $("#<%=gvEmployees.ClientID%> input[id*='chkIsMarried']:checkbox").each(function (index) {
            if ($(this).is(':checked'))
                counter++;
        });
        alert(counter);
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:GridView ID="gvEmployees" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeId" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeName" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkIsMarried" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("IsMarried") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Button ID="btnGetMarried" runat="server" Text="Server" OnClick="btnGetMarried_Click" /><br />
    <input type="button" value="Client" onclick="GetMarriedEmployees()" />
</asp:Content>
```

**Code behind:**

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                List<Employees> employees = new List<Employees>()
            {
                new Employees{EmployeeId=1, EmployeeName="Bob", IsMarried=true},
                new Employees{EmployeeId=2, EmployeeName="John", IsMarried=true}
            };

                gvEmployees.DataSource = employees;
                gvEmployees.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void btnGetMarried_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        int marriedEmployees = 0;
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvEmployees.Rows)
        {
            var isMarried = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkIsMarried");
            if(isMarried.Checked)
                marriedEmployees++;
        } 

        Response.Write(String.Format("Number of married employees = {0}",marriedEmployees.ToString()));
    }

    public class Employees
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public bool IsMarried { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I suspect that you may be a VB.NET developer so here is the VB version of the server side code:

```
Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then

            Dim employees As New List(Of Employees)

            Dim employee1 As Employees = New Employees()
            employee1.EmployeeId = 1
            employee1.EmployeeName = "Bob"
            employee1.IsMarried = False

            Dim employee2 As Employees = New Employees()
            employee2.EmployeeId = 2
            employee2.EmployeeName = "John"
            employee2.IsMarried = True

            employees.Add(employee1)
            employees.Add(employee2)

            gvEmployees.DataSource = employees
            gvEmployees.DataBind()

        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnGetMarried_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnGetMarried.Click
        Dim marriedEmployees As Integer = 0
        For Each row As GridViewRow In gvEmployees.Rows

            Dim isMarried As CheckBox = row.FindControl("chkIsMarried")
            If isMarried.Checked Then
                marriedEmployees += 1
            End If
        Next

        Response.Write(String.Format("Number of married employees = {0}", marriedEmployees))

    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Employees
    Public Property EmployeeId As Integer
    Public Property EmployeeName As String
    Public Property IsMarried As Boolean
End Class
```

Answer (score 5):

A javascript solution:

```
function CheckBoxCount() {
    var gv = document.getElementById("<%= Gridview1.ClientID %>");
    var inputList = gv.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var numChecked = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
        if (inputList[i].type == "checkbox" && inputList[i].checked) {
            numChecked = numChecked + 1;
        }
    }
    alert(numChecked);
}
```

**Markup**:

```
       <asp:GridView AllowSorting="true" ID="Gridview1" Width="98%" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="cb_count" runat="server" onclick="CheckBoxCount();"></asp:CheckBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                ...
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim cnt as Integer = 0
For i=0 to GridView1.Rows.Count -1
   Dim chk as CheckBox = TryCast( GridView1.Row(i).Controls.Find("nameOfCheckBoxControlColum"),CheckBox)
if chk.Checked=True Then cnt += 1
Next

'Now cnt holds the number of Checked Boxes.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = $('input[name="numbChecked"]:checked').length;
```

it's the easiest way to get the count without any trouble and extra explanation! :)

Comment: You should really accompany your answer with an explanation of each section.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
function Calculation()
{
    var grid = document.getElementById("<%=grdSelectFees.ClientID%>"); //grdSelectFees GridViewId
    for (var i = 0; i < grid.rows.length - 1 ; i++) 
    {
        var CheckBox1 = $("input[id*=chkRow]")//chkRow Id of Check box
        if (CheckBox1[i].type == "checkbox" && CheckBox1[i].checked)
        {
            //Code For If check Box Is Checked
        }
    }
}
```